# How to style Stackpanel's children?

Tags: silverlight, styles, stackpanel

Here is my scenario. I have a stackpanel i want to style the children inside it.
so i want to write a style for my stackpanel  in which i mention the default style of all its chidrens.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Exactly what i need in this [link](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx)
 The concept called Implicit Styles.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (it internaly uses `StackPanel`) class and define your [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).